# Trouble while creating layout

Tags: html, css

[I want to create a panel like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xzp2q.png)[][2]
I'm designing a html page where i want to display code in different languages. I'm trying to create a layout with 2 options(Java and Python) on top of the layout. It is something like viewing code for solutions in geeks for geeks website. Can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

Use `highlight.js`: https://highlightjs.org/

Another option is `Prismjs`: http://prismjs.com/